# Columns of sql table is to be inserted to another table row wise

Tags: sql-server

I'm using sql R2 server. And i want to, Columns of sql table is to be inserted to another table row wise. Something like below. Please help me out here. Sorry my English is not so proper. I have attached screenshot here.

Here is my table :

```
Customer id     Member Code     Account Type

C000100000003   A0001000000003  SB

000100000007    R0001000000001  SB

C000100000010   R0001000000001  SB

C000100000007   R0001000000002  SB
```

And i want in the format like this

```
Customer id     Member Code     Account Type     Customer id     Member Code    Account Type    Customer id     Member Code     Account Type

C000100000003   A0001000000003  SB               C000100000003   A0001000000003  SB              C000100000003   A0001000000003   SB     

000100000007    R0001000000001  SB               C000100000003   A0001000000003  SB              C000100000003   A0001000000003   SB     

C000100000010   R0001000000001  SB               C000100000003   A0001000000003  SB              C000100000003   A0001000000003   SB     

C000100000007   R0001000000002  SB               C000100000003   A0001000000003  SB              C000100000003   A0001000000003   SB
```

Thanks

Comment: First you need to decide which DBMS you are using. mysql <> sql server. Then you need to explain the logic here.

Comment: I am using MS Sql R2.

Comment: Judging from your example, it looks like you just want to split your results across two display columns so they are not as long of a displayed list. If this is the case, you are much better off doing such things client side.

Comment: Great. Now we know which DBMS you are using. Can you try the second part? Explaining what this output is. It looks like you are just duplicating the same data over and over. How do you know which data to copy?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
INTO myNewTable
FROM myOldTable
```